# How to round the border corners inside the style prop of the VictoryLegend component?

Tags: reactjs, victory-charts

I want to create a legend for a graph using the `VictoryLegend` component. I put a border and want to put rounded corners. Here is the code:

```
<VictoryLegend
   x={300}
   y={15}
   orientation="horizontal"
   style={{
   border: { stroke: '#808080' },
   }}
   gutter={13}
   data={[
      {
      name: 'regular',
      symbol: { fill: '#808080', type: 'minus' },
      labels: { fontFamily: 'Lato', fontSize: 10 },
      },
    ]}
  />
```

How can I do it? I tried using `borderRadius` inside the `border` object, outside of it, and nothing worked.

Answer (score 2):

Never worked with victory-charts and this is first time I heard about it. So maybe I'm wrong but from the source I can see following.

VictoryLegend accept [borderComponent](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/victory/blob/abe771e662120799b2acbb4efef07868612a69ff/packages/victory-legend/src/victory-legend.js#L32) which is any simple component. I bet you should be able to do something like

```
<VictoryLegend
  borderComponent={<rect rx="15"/>}
/>
```

borderComopnent should be native SVG comopnent I guess.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/rect

Answer (score 0):

The VictoryLegend component has a prop to replace the default border component.

As documented [here](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-legend/#bordercomponent), you can pass in a component instance which will be responsible for rendering a border around the legend. You can style this component's looks in any which way you like.

```
 <VictoryLegend
   borderComponent={<RoundedBorder width={300}/>}
   x={300}
   y={15}
   orientation="horizontal"
   style={{
   border: { stroke: '#808080' },
   }}
   gutter={13}
   data={[
      {
      name: 'regular',
      symbol: { fill: '#808080', type: 'minus' },
      labels: { fontFamily: 'Lato', fontSize: 10 },
      },
    ]}
  />
```

Here is a RoundedBorder component that I put together, let me know if it works.

```
import React from "react";

const RoundedBorder = (props) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line react/prop-types
  const { desc, ...rest } = props;
  return desc ? (
    <>
      <rect
        rx="15"
        vectorEffect="non-scaling-stroke"
        {...rest}
      >
        <desc>{desc}</desc>
      </rect>
    </>
  ) : (
    <rect
      rx="15"
      vectorEffect="non-scaling-stroke"
      {...rest}
    />
  );
};
export default RoundedBorder;
```

Comment: `<rect>` is native SVG element. I think you need to use rx attribute to round it